# perl interpreter on blackberry phone

Tags: perl, blackberry, interpreter

is there a way to run perl scripts (just easy samples) on a blackberry?. 
I heard a rumor that there are some interpreters for mobile platforms,thanks.
otherwise, anybody knows how-to use android on a blackberry mobile

Answer (score 2):

- You can run Perl (as well as other "scripting" languages) on Android via [Scripting Layer](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/).
- You can run native Android apps on SOME blackberry OS devices, specifically [Playbook](http://www.androidcentral.com/first-look-android-apps-blackberry) tablet